# OpenGL with glTexCoord - Images with many tiles could get tedious?

Tags: java, image, opengl, lwjgl

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRXcy.png

This image is a 78*24 image of the alphabet, with each letter in a 6*6, so 52 total squares.

Wouldn't using glTexCoord to get a single letter out of that image get kind of tedious?

```
  GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);

  GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0769f,0);

  GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0769f,0.25f);

  GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0.25f);
```

Since 1/13(0.0769) of 78 is 6 and 1/4(0.25) of 24 is 6, is this kind of what I'm looking to do, to single out a letter? I'm just making sure this is the way to go.

Comment: It might be tedious, but you can always write a function that will abstract out the details and then in the actual drawing code, just call that function.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm on the right track then. And yea, automating it sounds like a good idea, I'll work on something that does that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to write a function/method to create the texture coordinates for a single character. Since you know the number of characters as well as the dimensions you might just pass the character into that method, calculate the coordinates and return those, e.g.

```
Vector2D[] getCharacterCoords(char c) {
  //calculate the coords with the knowledge that you have 78 * 24 pixels and a character is 6 * 6
  //thus resulting in a 13 * 4 character grid.

  //Note: since ASCII 'A' is code 65 and 'a' is 97 you'd need to subtract those values accordingly
}
```